# How do I debug why my aws iot remote job is stuck in queued?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, firmware-update

I have an aws IoT core MQTT broker that's working. I can connect to it and get message to various topics. But when I create a "remote job"

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/jobs-comm-notifications.html

and target my device, it runs the job, says completed. But it says 1 job queued and 0 success now for the last hour. Will my client ever get a job notification? How can I debug why it's stuck in queued?

https://i.imgur.com/OdQkqNy.png

[aws screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OojvN.png)